# Updating record fails after renaming table

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am missing something I am sure.
I had a table named LMdata and I renamed it to WFData.
Now, I am unable to update a record using MySQL workbench and Cloud SQL complains that it cannot find the old table.

Executing:
UPDATE `lmlaser`.`WFData` SET `B1LaserQty` = '0' WHERE (`RowNum` = '1624');

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1146: 1146: Table 'lmlaser.LMdata' doesn't exist

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Thanks,
Jayaram

Answer (score 1):

In order to refresh the MySql tables in the database you can execute the command "flush tables",if the MySQL workbench still not recognizing the changes try from the MySQl console client and go inside the database with the command "use database" make the updates , then execute "flush tables"  and "show tables" to verify the changes.

As well You can connect directly to following the instructions Connect to your instance with the MySQL client in Cloud Shell[1] and execute the commands previously commented

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart#connect